# viewdidload issue xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, viewcontroller, viewdidload, viewwillappear

i just learn how to change switch between views with push and pop.
now, to my second view i add a label witch i wand to change her value every time my second view is push.
i add the label, connect her to my file owner's and i use viewdidload to change her value.
when i entered to my second view nothing is happed. but when i use viewdidapper all work perfect(but it take a second until the label value is update).

my code is:
mysecondviewcontroller.h:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
     IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
     NSString *label;
}

@property (copy) NSString *label;

@end
```

mysecondviewcontroller.m(ofcourse i synthesize label):

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   textLabel.text = label;
   NSLog(@"viewdidapper2");
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
   textLabel.text = label;
   [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewdidload2");

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

my firstviewcontroller.m(IBAction):

```
- (IBAction)pushViewController:(id)sender
{
    static int count = 1;

    SecondViewController *secondVieController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVieController animated:YES];   
   secondVieController.title = @"second";
   secondVieController.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number: %d", count];     

   count++;

}
```

what is the problem in my viewdidload?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `viewDidLoad`, you need to call the super function before doing anything else.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   textLabel.text = label;
    NSLog(@"viewdidload2");

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

I think that there is another issue, you are setting `secondVieController.label` after pushing the view controller, but this means at the time that `viewDidLoad` runs, `secondVieController.label` is still empty. This should fix it.

```
- (IBAction)pushViewController:(id)sender
{
    static int count = 1;

    SecondViewController *secondVieController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    secondVieController.title = @"second";
    secondVieController.label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number: %d", count];     
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVieController animated:YES];   

    count++;

}
```

Comment: In fact, this is true of almost any function that you're overriding. There are exceptions though, notably the dealloc function when you're not using ARC which the super function is the last thing you call.

Comment: I like to think of it this way - call super first on the way "in" - init, viewWillAppear, etc, and call it last on the way out - dealloc, viewWillDisappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you Want to Update Label Every Time when View Loaded Then You have to Write the code in to Viewwillappear Method.